# returning another node based on a condition in groovy

Tags: groovy, scripting

My XML is like:

```
<app>
   <module>
      <web>
         <web-uri>abc.war</web-uri>
         <context-root>abc</context-root>
      </web>
   </module>
   <module>
      <web>
         <web-uri>abc.pl</web-uri>
         <context-root>adf</context-root>
      </web>
   </module>
</app>
```

I need the `context-root` values only if `web-uri` value ends with *war*. As a List.

I wrote something like:

```
def ctxRootList = nodeList.'**'.findAll{
        ctxRoot -> 
                    ctxRoot.module.web."web-uri".text().endsWith(".war") 
    }*.text()
```

There are 2 problems here:

1. I do not know how to get the other sibling rather the `web-uri` value
2. The result now seems to be returned as a concatenated string of all those values. So, how to make it return as a list of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def txt = '''
<app>
    <module>
            <web>
                <web-uri>abc.war</web-uri>
                <context-root>abc</context-root>
            </web>
        </module>
        <module>
            <web>
                <web-uri>abc.pl</web-uri>
                <context-root>adf</context-root>
            </web>
    </module>
</app>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(txt)
xml.module.web.findAll { it.'web-uri'.text().endsWith('war') }*.'context-root'*.text()
```

The trick is to search for `web` elements - parent of both `web-uri` and `context-root`. If such element is found you can easily refer to it's children.

Comment: why another star after context-root in the end?

Comment: @Vik because there might be multiple `context-root` elements so `text()` is invoked on every element found.